# Date range input VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, range

I have to work with a start date and an end date.

A user has to to key them into text boxes on a userform in the format “mm” and “yyyy”. I’ve set the text limit of each text box to 2 and 4 respectively.

As soon as the user types 2 digits, the focus should go to the next box. How can I achieve that?

As there’ll be a start and end date: How can I loop all data, e. g. from 201702 to 201904?

Comment: Overall readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. This will check if the textbox holds two characters and if it holds a numeric value. Then, it will set the focus to the second textbox

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If Not (KeyCode = vbKeyBack Or KeyCode = vbKeyDelete Or (47 < KeyCode And KeyCode < 58) Or (95 < KeyCode And KeyCode < 106)) Then
    If Len(Me.TextBox1.Value) = 1 Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    Else
        Me.TextBox1.Value = Left(Me.TextBox1.Value, 1)
    End If
End If
If Len(Me.TextBox1) = 2 And IsNumeric(Me.TextBox1) Then
    Me.TextBox2.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Looping through a date range can be done as follows

```
Sub loopthroughdates()
Dim d As Date
For d = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) To DateSerial(2020, 1, 1)
    'Do stuff
Next d
End Sub
```

Comment: You could add a check on `KeyCode` to ensure only numeric values are accepted?

Comment: @tim stack Thank you! It works great, however, I’m stuck at another juncture, extracting all the years and months between them and sticking them tgt in a string form yyyymm

Comment: That's another question and if you can't find a solution, feel free to open a new thread. If this helped you, please don't forget to accept the answer :)